# Apply filter to all but first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to apply multiple filters on a dynamic html table. It is working fine but the first row contains the headings like empID, Name, etc. It can't be considered as  as they are considered as  only. I tried something like this but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $rows = $('#tblData tr');
    console.log("akshansh");
    $('#empId, #empName,#status').on('input', function() {
        var val1 = $.trim($('#empId').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        var val2 = $.trim($('#empName').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        var val3= $.trim($('#status').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text1 = $(this).find('tr:not(:first),td:nth-child(1)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();   
            var text2 = $(this).find('tr:not(:first),td:nth-child(2)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            var text3 = $(this).find('tr:not(:first),td:nth-child(n+2)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text1.indexOf(val1) || !~text2.indexOf(val2)|| !~text3.indexOf(val3);
        }).hide();
    }); 
});
```

Also the third column onwards are the date fields so is there a way that i can filter the data datewise?

Comment: Try `var $rows = $('#tblData > tr').not(':first')`

Comment: Nopes, not working. Applying it stopped filteration also.

Comment: If you provide your HTML we might be able to suggest a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the : before first-child

```
$("#tblData tr:not(:first-child)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Structure your table to look like

```
 <table id='tblData'>
     <thead>
         <tr></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Put your first row in the thead, then  put the rest in the tbody.

That will allow you to qualify you jquery

```
var $rows = $('#tblData tbody tr');
```

Comment: Data is being read from .xlsx file and it is considering the heading row also as normal row